# Replace variable string in VBA

Tags: vba, string, excel, replace

I need to replace somethin in a string, but what to replace may vary. It can be

```
XY - test
XXxY-test
XXyyXx-TEST
yXyy     -Test
```

and virtually any other combination of whitespaces and cases of the above.

I need to replace the "-test" part and leave the "XXX" alone. So, when using a simple replace

```
Replace("XXX  -test", "- test", "")
```

It won't work, obviously. So I need a more sophisticated version of Replace that could handle this task. Is there something I could use or do I have to write it on my own?

Comment: RegEx([see this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=480272)) may work for you.  I'm not sure what your pattern string would look like, but there's lots of sites for writing those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need more flexibility than that provided by mj82's method (for example, you may not know the length of the initial expression), you can use a regular expression.  For example:

```
Regex.Replace("XXX  -test", "\s*-\s*test", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your function and am getting an object doesn't exist error. When I add a watch for "Regex" it says that the object is empty. Any ideas why this is happening? Do I need to load a library? I'm in Excel 2010

Comment: You need to add `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions` to your references (current version is I think 5.5), then declare the variable using: `Dim Regex as New Regexp`.

Answer (score 8):

This is to compliment eggyal's answer. This is a VBA regexreplace function so that you can use his answer. You'll notice I added ignore_case as an option for flexibility, so your call would be:

```
=RegexReplace(cell, "\s*-\s*test", "", TRUE)
```

Here is the function, I hope you find it useful:

```
' -------------------------------------------------------------------
' Search and Replace using a regular expression
' -------------------------------------------------------------------

Function RegexReplace(ByVal text As String, _
                      ByVal replace_what As String, _
                      ByVal replace_with As String, _
                      Optional ByVal ignore_case As Boolean = False) As String

Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.ignorecase = ignore_case
RE.pattern = replace_what
RE.Global = True
RegexReplace = RE.Replace(text, replace_with)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If XXX is first, you can use Left(string; 3) function tu cut 3 (or any length you need) letters from left side, then you don't care what's after it.

Comment: Okay, I forgot to clarify that in the question. XXX is also variable of any character (maybe even including "test" and alike)

Comment: If you can cut until "-" sign (and it cannot be in XXX expression), then this may help: Left(mystr, InStr(mystr, "-") - 1), it cuts all the letters until first occurance of "-". Otherwise - Regex is best solution.