# Stop words in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project in excel and I am taking a text file, reading the text file, and trying to remove the stop words from the text file. But I'm getting stuck on removing the stop words in excel VBA. From the research I've seen it's possible in Java and PHP but I haven't been able to find one specifically to excel VBA. Is there a function that will remove stop words in excel VBA?

Comment: There is no existing function, but if you have a list of stop words then you can use regexp in a loop to do this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883725/replace-variable-string-in-vba

Comment: For my ignorance, what is "stop words"?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Const InputTxtFile As String = "C:\Temp\InTxt.txt"
 Const OutputTxtFile As String = "C:\Temp\OutTxt.txt"
 Const ListOfStopWords As String = ";CAT;DOG;FOX;"

Sub main()

Dim DataLine As String
Dim strTempLine As String

Open InputTxtFile For Input As #1   'Or FreeFile()
Open OutputTxtFile For Append As #2

While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, DataLine

    Dim LineTab() As String
    LineTab = Split(DataLine, " ") 'Split readed line on space

    If UBound(LineTab) > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(LineTab)
            If (InStr(ListOfStopWords, ";" + LineTab(i) + ";") = 0) Then 'Look if not in Stop Words list
                strTempLine = strTempLine + LineTab(i) + " "
            End If
        Next
        Print #2, strTempLine 'Print to output file
        strTempLine = ""
    End If

Wend

Close #1
Close #2

End Sub
```

'Ref: [Read/Parse text file line by line in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba)